# drop piece of photo automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, puzzle, droppable

I used droppable and draggable for puzzle. 
But now when i drop i have this.
http://prntscr.com/77b4he

The dropplaces becomes bigger and change color.
I want that my pictures fill that square complete.
And also that the pictures automatically stands in the middle/correct.

this is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/gladius/kj76gxxr/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-gear" 
            }
        });
        $("img").draggable();
        $(".testdrop").droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" ).find( "img" ); 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is my script the other code is in the link

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends what your future plans are.

I'll answer your question, but I could imagine your next plans will require something different.  Anyway; I'll tell you something useful, that you ought to know.

After dropping the puzzle piece, I add that piece to the DOM of the table cell.
So, you add a little css:

```
#kader table td img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

extra javascript:

```
// Let's add the picture to the dom of the dropzone
$(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this));
// the dragged element has a style attribute, given by jQuery-UI.
// When we remove this, the image will be normally integrated in the <td>
$(ui.draggable).removeAttr('style');
```

---

Here's a copy/pastable example

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: green;
      }
      h1 {
        color: yellow;
      }
      .Levels {
        color:blue;
      }
      .Puzzels {
        width: 150px;
        margin: 25px;
        height: 150px;
      }
      .Levelhtml {
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        color: blue;
      }
      .testdrop {
        width: 50px;
        height:50px;
        margin: 0;

      }
      #droppable {
        width: 50px;
        height:50px;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .droppable {
        width:50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
      #kader {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
      }
      #kader table {
        width:270px;
        height: 270px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 0;
        display: table;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 2px;
        border-color: gray;
      }
      #kader table td {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: blue;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        /*position: relative;*/
      }
      #kader table td img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Jquery Puzzel</h1>
    <br><br><br>
      <div id="dragzone">
      <img id="puz1.1a"class="puz1"src="http://hollowworld.co.uk/data/avatars/m/12/12575.jpg?1389646383">
      <img id="puz1.1b"class="puz1"src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000858867494/rKSo8nRD_normal.jpeg">
      <img id="puz1.1c"class="puz1"src="http://s4.cdn.sanomamedia.be/a/view/q90/w50/h50/1313547/quokka.png">
      <img id="puz1.1d"class="puz1"src="http://www.konicaminolta.com/kids/endangered_animals/library/thumbnail/quokka.jpg">
      <img id="puz1.1e"class="puz1"src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-dfsDKZANqeI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAK4/zSpWgwxLIq4/photo.jpg?sz=50">
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    (Only the first row is droppable)
    <div id="Kader">
      <table><tr><td id="puzdrop1.1a" class="testdrop droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puzdrop1.1b" class="testdrop droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puzdrop1.1c" class="testdrop droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puzdrop1.1d" class="testdrop droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puzdrop1.1e" class="testdrop droppable ui-droppable"></td></tr><tr><td id="puz1.1.6" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.7" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.8" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.9" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.10" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td></tr><tr><td id="puz1.1.11" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.12" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.13" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.14" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.15" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td></tr><tr><td id="puz1.1.16" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.17" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.18" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.19" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.20" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td></tr><tr><td id="puz1.1.21" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.22" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.23" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.24" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td><td id="puz1.1.25" class="droppable ui-droppable"></td></tr></table>
    </div>
    <button class="reset">RESET</button>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").button({
          icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-gear" 
          }
        });
        $("img").draggable();
        $(".testdrop").droppable({
          drop: function( event, ui ) {
            // we highlight the dropzone ( the <td> )
            $(this).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" ).find("img");
            // Let's add the picture to the dom of the dropzone
            $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this));
            // the dragged element has a style attribute, given by jQuery-UI.
            // When we remove this, the image will be normally integrated in the <td>
            $(ui.draggable).removeAttr('style');
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Are you Dutch or Belgian? (#kader)

Comment: tnx for help. I am Belgian :)

Comment: If I add your code, my puzzle doesn't works anymore. I can't drag pieces anymore after that. Do you also know how it can hold my piece? So if i come to the square that it automatically 'takes' the piece?

Comment: Yes, I know; you didn't mention that; as I said, I answered the specific question about resizing and positioning, not the solution for your final puzzle.   The final solution will be simpler than your code is now.  Less (and smarter) HTML, and a bit of other reasoning; then my code will work.  Probably better to start a new question.